# How to avoid code duplication maintaining information hiding trough polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism, state, code-duplication, information-hiding

I wrote the following two classes (implementing a state pattern):

Price:

```
public abstract class Price {


    public abstract double getAmount(int rentalDays);

    public abstract  int getPriceCode();

}
```

RegularPrice:

```
public class RegularPrice extends Price {

    private static final int _priceCode = 0;


    @Override
    public double getAmount(int rentalDays) {
        double res = 2;
        if (rentalDays > 2)
            res += (rentalDays - 2) * 1.5;
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPriceCode() {
        return _priceCode;
    }
}
```

The problem is that adding other subclasses of Price with differents `_priceCode` translates into code duplication for the `getPriceCode()` method.
I thought about pulling up the method to the superclass but then I couldn't declare `_priceCode` private.

What's the standard solution?

Comment: Are you over-thinking things? Why not simply make priceCode a private non-static field with a setter method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any reasons why `getPriceCode()` has to stay in the derived class since it is a common behaviour to all subclasses, so put it the base class. So `_priceCode` is in `Price` and not assigned and it should be declared as **protected** or **package** (depends if you want to let free access to it only from subclasses in the same package or even if from subclasses that belong to another package).

#### Price

```
public abstract class Price {
    protected static final int _priceCode;    // do you really need static?

    Price(int p){ this._priceCode=p;}
    public abstract double getAmount(int rentalDays);
    public int getPriceCode(){ return _priceCode; }

}
```

#### RegularPrice

```
public class RegularPrice extends Price {

     RegularPrice(int p){ 
         //many ways to do this, but use costructors to set members
         super(p); 
      } 

    public double getAmount(int rentalDays) {
        double res = 2;
        if (rentalDays > 2)
            res += (rentalDays - 2) * 1.5;
        return res;
    }

}
```

In this way, `_priceCode` is *directly* visible only from subclasses of **Price**, from other parts of code it can be accessed only using the getter method and `getPriceCode()` is not duplicated.

Comment: Actually I made _priceCode static because the class / _priceCode relationship never changes. I thought about removing final and setting the value whit a static initializer, is it a good approach?

Comment: Not sure of this, how could many `Item`s (i.e the Context of State pattern) use only a variable `_priceCode`? If every item has his own pricecode, what does it happen if many Items are active? I think you'll have problem to manage the access to the member...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple options:

1) Remove the "private" keyword to make it a "package" level access.

2) Add a getter and/or setter to the superclass to provide the type of access you desire.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this approach.

```java
public abstract class Price {
    protected final int _priceCode;

    public Price(int priceCode) {
        this._priceCode = priceCode;
    }

    public final int getPriceCode() {
        return this._priceCode;
    }

    public abstract double getAmount(int rentalDays);
}
```

```java
public class RegularPrice extends Price {

    public RegularPrice() {
        super(0);  // put the default priceCode here, or use a private final static int PRICE_CODE = 0 to avoid magic number
    }

    @Override
    public double getAmount(int rentalDays) {
        double res = 2;
        if (rentalDays > 2)
            res += (rentalDays - 2) * 1.5;
        return res;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-dump answers as they're as bad as code-dump questions and will not likely help future visitors. At least explain your answer as well, and in fact more effort should be put into the explanation than the code.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Price {
   private int _priceCode;
   public double getAmount(int rentalDays);

   public int getPriceCode() {
    return _priceCode;
   }
}
```

Do this on the subclass:

```
public class RegularPrice extends Price {

  private int _priceCode = 0;


  @Override
  public double getAmount(int rentalDays) {
    double res = 2;
    if (rentalDays > 2)
        res += (rentalDays - 2) * 1.5;
    return res;
  }

  @Override
  public void setPriceCode(int priceCode) {
    _priceCode = priceCode;
  }
}
```

Comment: A setter method for a `final` variable??

Comment: Also same comment as given to mckuok -- your answer would be much better if you gave it more explanation for why you propose the code you've posted. The goal for this site is to provide answers that are helpful to all future visitors, not just the original poster.